# Using the same ID for multiple combo-boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

**I need to assign an ID** to jquery autocomplete Combobox **but i have multiple** jquery autocomplete Combobox in page
i am using this line `input.attr("id", "anyThng");` to assign ID to jquery autocomplete Combobox

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

**code for reference:**

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var input, self = this, select = this.element.hide(), selected = select.children(":selected"), value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "", wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>").addClass("ui-combobox").insertAfter(select);

            input = $("<input>")
            // .id("something")
                    .appendTo(wrapper)
                    .val(value)
                    .addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input")
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                // alert(text);
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }));
                          //     alert(input.val());
                            //   alert(input.attr('id'));
                          // input.attr("id", this.id);
                           // alert(input.attr('id'));
                        },

                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function(event, ui) {

                            //alert(input[0].id);

                            // alert($(event.target)[0].id);
                            // alert($(this).attr('id'));
                            // alert($("#something").attr('id'));
                            // alert(event.target.id);
                            // alert($(".ui-state-default ui-combobox-input ui-autocomplete-input").attr("id"));

                            if (!ui.item) {
                                xT = $(this).val();
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children("option").each(function() {
                                    if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if (!valid) {

                                    xT = $(this).val();
                                    if (countryID == '' || countryID == undefined) {
                                        $(".selPnext").hide();
                                        $("#Tr3").hide();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        // Checking saudi Province
                                        $("#status").val("21");
                                        if (countryID == 1500000090) {
                                            if (comissionarY == '' || comissionarY == undefined) {
                                                //comissionary
                                                if (ProcvID == '' || ProcvID == undefined) {
                                                    $(".selPnext").hide();
                                                    $("#Tr3").hide();
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    $(".selPnext").show();
                                                    $("#Tr3").show();
                                                    $("#Td3").html("Comissionary Status (20/21)");
                                                    $("#status").val("21");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                //center
                                                if (ProcvID == '' || ProcvID == undefined) {
                                                    $(".selPnext").hide();
                                                    $("#Tr3").hide();
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    $(".selPnext").show();

                                                    if (countryID == 1500000090) {
                                                        $("#Td3").html("Center Status (22/23)");
                                                        $("#status").val("22");
                                                        $("#Tr3").show();
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        $("#Tr3").hide();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            if (countryID != 1500000090) {
                                                $(".selPnext").show();
                                                $("#Tr3").show();
                                            }
                                            //$("#Div1").css({ width: "400px" });
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    // $(this).val("");
                                    // select.val("");
                                    // input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
            //.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

            input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
            };

            $("<a>")
                    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                    .appendTo(wrapper)
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                            input.autocomplete("close");
                            return;
                        }

                        // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                        $(this).blur();

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        input.focus();
                    });
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
            //added  n cam b deleted
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
var xT;
function myVal() {
    return xT;
}
$(function() {
    //$("#tryy").combobox();
//$("#country").combobox();
});
```

Comment: create snippet on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ID`'s are supposed to be unique, why don't you change them to share the same `Class` and then use that in your function.

Comment: I NEED to place the below code line in the above code file
wen $("#abc").Combox(); get called

input.attr("id", ComboIDs + "Auto");